# How to create a .dylib C extension on mac os x with distutils and/or setuptools?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, setuptools, distutils, python-c-extension

I need to make a C extension with distutils (and/or setuptools) that can be used BOTH dynamically at runtime, and at compile time (for different purposes).  This isn't a problem on Linux, but it's an issue on OS X.  By default, distutils creates a "bundle" on OS X (and names it .so), which can be used at runtime, but NOT at compile time.  I need to make a .dylib, which can be linked to at compile time, and I need to do it within a setup.py that I can package for PyPI.

No matter what I try, distutils keeps creating a bundle, and when I try to link against this library, I get an error.  You can check explicitly whether distutils created a bundle or dynamically linked library by using file on the command line:

```
file libA.so
libA.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

The following cc command gives me what I want:

```
cc -fPIC -shared source1.o source2.o -o libA.so
file libA.so
libA.so: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked for me (added lines in my `setup.py`):

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    from distutils import sysconfig
    vars = sysconfig.get_config_vars()
    vars['LDSHARED'] = vars['LDSHARED'].replace('-bundle', '-dynamiclib')
```

This configuration seems to be hard-wired in the module `_sysconfigdata`. It's also overridable using environment variables, so this works as well:

```
LDSHARED="cc -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F." python setup.py install
```

Comment: Sorry the late response, but I just tried this, and both methods leave me with a 'bundle' after I check with `file libA.so` (or if I try to compile linking libA.so I get the same 'can't link with bundle, only dylibs' error).  Any suggestions?

Comment: In the output of `setup.py build`, under "`running build_ext`", it shows the actual command lines used for compilation and link. Look at the link command (the last one, that creates the .so file), is it affected by the LDSHARED def? Or by other environment vars in `sysconfig.get_config_vars()`? If so, perhaps you can try to tweak these vars. If all else fails you can debug `distutils/command/build_ext.py` to see how it generates the arguments to `self.compiler.link_shared_object()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something important, because I tried again, and not only do I now get a dynamically linked library, I can't get a bundle now (I need both for different purposes).  I tried the same code but switching replace('-dynamiclib', '-bundle'), and still get a dynamically linked library.  When I print sysconfig.get_config_vars(), I get all -bundle and no -dynamiclib.  Your debugging suggestions are very helpful, but when I tried python setup.py build, I get "running build_ext" but with no output below it.  Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the build goes through in that case? Perhaps you need to delete the `build` folder to re-build?

Comment: Thanks so much!  That resolves both problems at once.  Removing the build folder brings up all the print statements (because something's actually getting built!) and gets me a bundle or dynamically linked library as I want using your code.  Silly mistake!  Is it good practice for setup.py to clean the directory before installing?  Most people would be installing my package with pip.

Comment: No. Normally setup.py would re-build only if the actual C source has changed, and usually that makes perfect sense. It only fails if you modify the build process itself (as you did during its development). If in your case you plan to support two build modes (bundle vs. dynamic), I would suggest having a different output location for each mode to avoid this kind of mistake.