# Distutils setup generate .so and not .dylib on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, compilation, distutils

I've been trying to create C bindings for a Python library following an official tutorial presented by the developer of the latter library using Cython (https://www.ibisc.univ-evry.fr/~fpommereau/SNAKES/snakes-out-of-python.html).

The *cythonization* of the library works perfectly. However, when calling the creation of the library file with **distutils.core.setup** on *Mac OS X 10.10.5*, it produces a file *.so*. However, when I need to compile the example *.c* file with the library, I end up having the following error message:

```
ld: can't link with bundle (MH_BUNDLE) only dylibs (MH_DYLIB) file './libsnk.so' for architecture x86_64
```

I've looking through the documentation of **distutils.core.setup** to see if there was any way to specify the type of file generated (in my case *.dylib*), unsuccessfully.

I've tried to follow the tutorial using a virtual machine running *Ubuntu 14.04.3* and I was able to make it work easily.

Is there a way to overcome this problem? Is there a way to specify to **distutils.core.setup** that it must generate a file with the *.dylib* format? Is there a way to make it work with *distutils.core.setup* still generating a file with the *.so* format?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to do something similar, for me this answer helped: [How to create a .dylib C extension on mac os x with distutils and/or setuptools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419594/how-to-create-a-dylib-c-extension-on-mac-os-x-with-distutils-and-or-setuptools)

The key code fragment was:

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    from distutils import sysconfig
    vars = sysconfig.get_config_vars()
    vars['LDSHARED'] = vars['LDSHARED'].replace('-bundle', '-dynamiclib')
```

Added to setup.py